# user login using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm gettin sql processing error sql:underfined here.Here i'm check whether the login form matched with the database called student and if there is a matched then an alert popup with welcome message and transfer to the next page.How do i fix the code?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            var db;


            function onDeviceReady() {

                db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Student",2*1024*1024);
                db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);

            }
 function loginForm(){
              db.transaction(checkDB, errorCB);
              $.mobile.changePage("#page5",{reverse:false,transition:"slide"});
              return false;
           }

      function checkDB(tx){
      var _matric=$("[name='matric']").val();
      var _password=$("[name='password']").val();
      var sql ='select * from STUDENT where matric='+_matric+' and password='+_password+'';
      tx.executeSql(sql,[],successLoginDB,errorCB);
      }

      function successLoginDB(tx,results){
      var len = results.rows.length;
      var _name =$("[name='name']").val();
      if (len==1) {alert("Welcome "+_name);}
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), fix it using args:

```
function loginForm(){
   db.transaction(checkDB, errorCB);
   $.mobile.changePage("#page5",{reverse:false,transition:"slide"});
   return false;
}

function checkDB(tx){
   var matric=$("[name='matric']").val();
   var password=$("[name='password']").val();
   var sql ='select * from STUDENT where matric = ? and password = ?';
   tx.executeSql(sql,[matric, password],successLoginDB,errorCB);
}

function successLoginDB(tx,results){
   var len = results.rows.length;
   var name =$("[name='name']").val();
   if (len==1) {alert("Welcome "+name);}
}
```

About error; I'm sure you are trying to use webSQL before cordova loads. You need wait for "DOM Ready" (for read text inputs) and "deviceready" for access to WebSQL:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var onDeviceReady = function () {
    // Start here.
}
```

Please, post more info.

Comment: that's my starting code but i'm still getting error